# Converting type inside quote! gives trait errors

Tags: rust, rust-proc-macros

I get this error:

> the trait `quote::to_tokens::ToTokens` is not implemented for
>   `proc_macro::Ident`

when I try to run this code:

```
#[proc_macro_hack]
pub fn between(input: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let idents = input
        .into_iter()
        .map(|i| match i {
            TokenTree::Ident(b) => {
                b
            },
            _ => panic!()
        })
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    let new_token_stream = quote! {
        (#(#idents),*)
    };

    new_token_stream.into()
}
```

This is how I want to use it:

```
fn main() {
    let a = 1;
    let b = 2;

    // Expand to (a, b);
    between!(a, b);
}
```

I also have a small project which holds above code: https://bitbucket.org/JoshSinne/pm/src/master/. Why can't I transform a `Ident` inside tokens? I tried using `parse`, `into` but that didn't worked out for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`syn` and `quote` are built against the alternative implementation of `proc_macro`, namely [proc_macro2](https://lib.rs/crates/proc-macro2). If you want to use them, you should first convert your `proc_macro::TokenStream` into [`proc_macro2::TokenStream`](https://docs.rs/proc-macro2/1.0.10/proc_macro2/struct.TokenStream.html), make any operations necessary, and at the end convert back. Both these conversion can be made using `From`/`Into`, since they are implemented in both directions.